# When dividing a number by its divisor in floating point math, when if ever is the result not an integral float

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, division, floating-accuracy

When I run this code in python

```
def is_cool(n):
    if (n/7).is_integer():
        return True
    else:
        return False

for i in range(0,1000000,7):
    if not is_cool(i):
        print(i, " is where the error is")
```

It doesn't print anything. I know there are some places where floating point math will always be correct. Is this one of them?

Comment: Can you include, what you expect vs what you got? and also why not use `%`

Comment: @TomKarzes I think the OP is asking, is a floating point number divided by one of it's divisiors guaranteed to result in an integer-float. I think that is guaranteed, but I don't know enough (re. much at all) about IEEE 754 to say

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hm, you may be right about that.  If the numerator and denominator are both integers, and can both be exactly represented (i.e. they aren't too large), then with a proper divider I would expect exact results.

Comment: If `n` is an integer representable as IEEE754 float, then all its integer divisors are representable as well. Your test however, will generate many false positives, e.g., every (double precision) float larger than `2**53` is an integer, so your test will become meaningless for large numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE-754 division of a number by one of its divisors returns an exact result.

IEEE 754-2008 4.3 says:

> … Except where stated otherwise, every operation shall be performed as if it first produced an intermediate result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then rounded that result according to one of the attributes in this clause.

When an intermediate result is representable, all of the rounding attributes round it to itself; rounding changes a value only when it is not representable. Rules for division are given in 5.4, and they do not state exceptions for the above.

The quotient resulting from dividing a representable number by a representable divisor must be representable, as it can have no more significant bits than the numerator. Therefore, dividing a number by one of its divisors returns an exact result.

Note that this rule applies to the numbers that are the actual operands of the division. When you have some numerals in source code, such as `1234567890123456890 / 7`, those numerals are first converted to the numeric format. If they are not representable in that format, some approximation must be produced. That is a separate issue from how the division operates.

Answer (score 0):

`(n/7).is_integer()` returns `True` only when `n%7===0`

Now you run your loop starting from `0` with a step size of `7`

Your `i` will be `0, 7, 14, 21, ...`

`is_cool(i)` will always return `True` for every value of `i` as stated above but in your `if` condition you have stated `if not is_cool(i)` will always be `False` hence code will not print anything

Comment: This doesn't address the question. They are asking *is there ever a case where this isn't true*, i.e., if an integral floating point number is divided by another integral floating point number which is its divisor, will the result always be an integral floating point number? I believe this *is* guaranteed, but I don't know enough about floating point representations to answer

Comment: Oh ... actually question language is not relevant enough so I believed that the question was related to printing error

Comment: "(n/7).is_integer() returns True only when n%7===0" - not true, due to rounding error. For example, it still gives True [when `n` is `3**60`](https://ideone.com/YQRF1z).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Wow thanks! Did you know that offhand or how did you find an example?

Comment: Do you think I should remove the python tags as it is not language specific? I thought it might be an implementation detail of is_integer but that seems to not be the case.

Comment: @peterduffy: I just picked a really big number not divisible by 7. When the result of a floating point division is sufficiently large, the result will always be an integer, because IEEE 754 binary64 format can't represent any finite non-integer values greater than 2**52.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ahh. That makes sense. I wonder if it can happen for numbers small enough that it wont run into that problem.

Comment: @peterduffy You could try something like `n=7*2**52 - 64` (the quotient in exact math is not an integer, but it will round to an integer, since the next non-integer is further away from the exact result)